# Pubnub and Cubism.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, polymer, pubnub, cubism.js

I'm using [pubnub](/questions/tagged/pubnub) to power a dashboard I'm developing.  All my widgets are based on code like this:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'widget-horizon',
    properties: { ... },
    ready: function() {
        registerCallback(this.channel, function (data) {

        }); 
    }
});
```

Then when that pubnub channel receives a message, the callback is called and passes the data.  For this particular chart, the data looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": "RegResponseTimes",
    "type": null,
    "timestamp": "2016-10-14T11:12:13.2313043-05:00",
    "data": [
        {
            "label": "Metric1",
            "Value": 0.05
        },
        {
            "label": "Metric2",
            "Value": 0.17
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to develop a widget based on cubism.js, but all the documentation is targeted at pulling data, more specifically using `Cube` or `Graphite`.

I'm having lots of trouble integrating the cubism code into my callback.  I'm stumbling over all the language like "Metric Accessor" and "Extents".

---

**After much trial and error, I kind of got one value working but here are the issues I need to fix:**

1. There is no actual chart, just the value.
2. I need one horizon for each data set.

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

And below is my full code (it's a polymer component). 
Major changes from the "random" sample include:

1. Stopping and starting the context.  I wasn't sure how else to keep it from ticking while I wasn't getting data.
2. Instead of pushing a random number, push one of the values as a POC.

   ```
       </style>
       <strong id="widgetName">{{name}}</strong>
       <div id="chart1"></div>
   </template>
   <script>

       var data = [];

       Polymer({
           is: 'widget-horizon',
           properties: {
               dataid: {
                   type: String
               },
               name: {
                   type: String
               },
               gethistory: {
                   type: Number
               },
               testvalue: {
                   type: Number
               },
               isloading: {
                   type: Boolean,
                   value: true
               }
           },
           ready: function() {
               var self = this;
               subscribe(self.dataid);
               getHistory(self.dataid,self.gethistory);
               registerCallback(this.dataid, function (data) {
                   context.start();
                   var y = data.data[0];
                   self.testvalue = y.Value;
                   self.isloading = false;
               });

               var context = cubism.context()
                       .serverDelay(0)
                       .clientDelay(0)
                       .step(1e4)
                       .size(600);
               var foo = setval("foo");

               var chart = self.$$('#chart1');
               d3.select(chart).call(function(div) {
                   div.append("div")
                           .attr("class", "axis")
                           .call(context.axis().orient("top"));
                   div.selectAll(".horizon")
                           .data([foo])
                           .enter().append("div")
                           .attr("class", "horizon")
                           .call(context.horizon().extent([0, 120]));
                   div.append("div")
                           .attr("class", "rule")
                           .call(context.rule());

               });


               function setval(name) {
                   var value = 0,
                           values = [],
                           last;
                   return context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
                       start = +start, stop = +stop;
                       if (isNaN(last)) last = start;
                       while (last < stop) {
                           last += step;
                           value = self.testvalue;
                           if (value != "") {
                               values.push(self.testvalue);
                               context.stop();
                           }
                       }
                       callback(null, values = values.slice((start - stop) / step));
                   }, name);
               }

               context.on("focus", function(i) {
                   d3.selectAll(".value").style("right", i == null ? null : context.size() - i + "px");
               });
           }
       });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Here is my full callback:

```
registerCallback(this.dataid, function (data) {
    if (self.isloading) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
            datas[i] = setval(data.data[i].MessageBodyClassName);
        }

        d3.select(chart).call(function(div) {
            div.append("div")
                    .attr("class", "axis")
                    .call(context.axis().orient("top"));
            div.selectAll(".horizon")
                    .data(datas)
                    .enter().append("div")
                    .attr("class", "horizon")
                    .call(context.horizon().extent([0, 120]));
            div.append("div")
                    .attr("class", "rule")
                    .call(context.rule());

        });
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
            vals[data.data[i].MessageBodyClassName] = data.data[i].Value;
        }
    }
    context.start();
    self.isloading = false;
});
```

And here is the converted `random` function:

```
function setval(name) {
    var value = 0,
            values = [],
            last;
    return context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
        start = +start, stop = +stop;
        if (isNaN(last)) last = start;
        while (last < stop) {
            last += step;
            value = self.testvalue;
            if (value != "") {
                values.push(vals[name]);
                context.stop();
            }
        }
        callback(null, values = values.slice((start - stop) / step));
    }, name);
}
```

essentially I just defined a global `vals` array and I'm using it to store the new values when pubnub updates and update the values with the Metric Accessor... I guess.